# Assign ComboBox to Display Int label

Tags: c#

Hey I'm new to SOF but have been using It alot to help myself. Anyway, I've been trying to get my items in my Combobox to display an int in my Race label. The Else works and for some reason when I click on the second item in the list it changes the StrRaceLbl to 1 but nothing else. Anyway out of Ideas and looked up about everything I could to try to figure this out. Any Info helps! Thanks.

```
private void RaceCmbBx_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num1, num2, num0;
    int index = RaceCmbBx.SelectedIndex;
    num1 = 1;
    num2 = 2;
    num0 = 0;

    if (index == 1)
    {
        StrRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
        DexRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
        ConRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
        WisRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
        IntRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
        ChaRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num0)).ToString();
    }
    if (index == 2)
    {
        StrRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
        DexRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
        ConRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
        WisRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
        IntRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
        ChaRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
    }
    else
        StrRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num2)).ToString();

    DexRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num2)).ToString();
    ConRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num2)).ToString();
    WisRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num2)).ToString();
    IntRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num2)).ToString();
    ChaRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num2)).ToString();
}
```

Also This Is what I used to add Items to the ComboBox:

```
// Content item for the combo box
private class Item
{
    public string Name;
    public int Value;
    public Item(string name, int value)
    {
        Name = name; Value = value;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        // Generates the text shown in the combo box
        return Name;
    }
}

public Ch_Creation()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Put some stuff in the combo box
    RaceCmbBx.Items.Add(new Item("Dragonborn", 1));
    RaceCmbBx.Items.Add(new Item("Dwarf", 2));
    RaceCmbBx.Items.Add(new Item("  Hill Dwarf", 3));
}

private void RaceCmbBx_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Display the Value property
    Item itm = (Item)RaceCmbBx.SelectedItem;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", itm.Name, itm.Value);
}
```

P.S Yes this is for D&D

Comment: You miss the braces around the assignements following the else statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you missed a couple of braces and an extra if statement (if I remember D&D character creation right :)

```
private void RaceCmbBx_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num1, num2, num0;
    int index = RaceCmbBx.SelectedIndex;
    num1 = 1;
    num2 = 2;
    num0 = 0;



    if (index == 1)
    {
        StrRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
        DexRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
        ConRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
        WisRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
        IntRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
        ChaRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num0)).ToString();
    }
    else if (index == 2)
    {
        StrRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
        DexRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
        ConRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
        WisRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
        IntRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
        ChaRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num1)).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
    StrRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num2)).ToString();
    DexRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num2)).ToString();
    ConRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num2)).ToString();
    WisRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num2)).ToString();
    IntRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num2)).ToString();
    ChaRaceLbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(num2)).ToString();
   }
}
```

Comment: It works for the most part but Its skipping the first Statement:

Comment: ComboBox is a 0 based index. So if you select the first value it's index 0 not 1

Answer (score 0):

Alright Guys Thanks for all the help! I re-twerked the code and It seems to be up and running now. I appreciate the assistance.

```
       private void RaceCmbBx_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num1, num2, num0;
        int index = RaceCmbBx.SelectedIndex;
        num1 = 1;
        num2 = 2;
        num0 = 0;

       if (index == 0)
        {
            StrRaceLbl.Text = num1.ToString();
            DexRaceLbl.Text = num1.ToString();
            ConRaceLbl.Text = num1.ToString();
            WisRaceLbl.Text = num1.ToString();
            IntRaceLbl.Text = num1.ToString();
            ChaRaceLbl.Text = num1.ToString();
        }
       else if (index == 1)
        {
            StrRaceLbl.Text = num2.ToString();
            DexRaceLbl.Text = num1.ToString();
            ConRaceLbl.Text = num2.ToString();
            WisRaceLbl.Text = num1.ToString();
            IntRaceLbl.Text = num1.ToString();
            ChaRaceLbl.Text = num2.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            StrRaceLbl.Text = num2.ToString();
            DexRaceLbl.Text = num0.ToString();
            ConRaceLbl.Text = num1.ToString();
            WisRaceLbl.Text = num0.ToString();
            IntRaceLbl.Text = num1.ToString();
            ChaRaceLbl.Text = num0.ToString();
        }
    }
```